# container_class doesn't seem to be working

Tags: menus

I'm new to WordPress and I'm not able to spot the error in my array passed as argument to `wp_nav_menu`.

Here is how I declare it

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => 'ul',
    'container_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'container_id' => '',
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
) ); ?>
```

But that's how my HTML is rendered:

```
<ul class="menu">
     <li class="page_item page-item-7 current_page_item">
         <a href="http://192.168.99.100:8080/">Home</a>
     </li>
     <li class="page_item page-item-2">
         <a href="http://192.168.99.100:8080/sample-page/">Sample Page</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

As you can see, the class of the container (the ul) is not the one I set. What's the problem?

EDIT: Using menu_class instead of container_class works well, but I don't understand: why does container influence the outer element and container_class doesn't? I'm a bit confused...

New declaration

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
    'menu_id' => '',
    'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
) ); ?>
```

New HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="page_item page-item-7 current_page_item">
        <a href="http://192.168.99.100:8080/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
        <a href="http://192.168.99.100:8080/sample-page/">Sample Page</a> 
    </li>
 </ul>
```

That's what I was looking for, but I don't understand how can it be right.
 And now, how can I remove the li classes? You know... I don't know how to refere to them since menu_class referes to the container and the container doesn't seem to refer to anything

Comment: Are you certain it's using that menu snippet? If you input a `container_id` it adds the ID correctly, as expected? I don't have a problem with the container class as it is now.

Comment: container_id is not working, but changing container to nav or div works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function generates HTML with both a container and UL menu. It will, by default, output some HTML structure that looks like this:

```
<div id="container_id" class="container_class">
    <ul id="menu_id" class="menu_class">
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Since you have defined the container as a `ul`, WordPress will try to keep the some valid HTML standards by only allowing the container to be one of 2 block level elements, [See Line 152](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7/src/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L152):

- `<div>`
- `<nav>`

You can filter it but I wouldn't suggest it. So by passing a `ul` to the container it ignores it and since it's being ignored it doesn't consider it a container and thus you cannot add a container class or container ID.

The `ul` would be your `menu` which is why you can add `menu_class` and `menu_id`.