# wp_nav_menu() doesn't apply correctly classes and IDs to menu and container

Tags: menus

I wrote this simple code to prove what I'm saying:

```
wp_nav_menu( [
    'menu' => 'Primary Navigation',
    'menu_class' => 'this-is-the-menu-class',
    'menu_id' => 'this-is-the-menu-id',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'this-is-the-container-class',
    'container_id' => 'this-is-the-container-ID',
] );
```

This is the output:

```
<div id="this-is-the-menu-id" class="this-is-the-menu-class">
    <ul>
        <li class="page_item page-item-2">
            <a href="http://localhost/test_site/index.php/pagina-di-esempio/">Example Page.</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**As you can see the `ul` element doesn't receive any class nor ID.**

**They, instead, are applied to the container and the container classes and ID seem to be simply missed (or getting the default values).**

In the documentation is told that

> - 'menu_class' (string) CSS class to use for the ul element which forms the menu. Default 'menu'.
> - 'menu_id' (string) The ID that is applied to the ul element which forms the menu. Default is the menu slug, incremented.
> - 'container' (string) Whether to wrap the ul, and what to wrap it with. Default 'div'.
> - 'container_class' (string) Class that is applied to the container. Default 'menu-{menu slug}-container'.
> - 'container_id' (string) The ID that is applied to the container.

**But as you can see the result is not the one expected.**

In [this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253192/container-class-doesnt-seem-to-be-working) the user set wrong the `container` param, and so the replies point out this error, but the error still exists and I'm doing all following the rules (at least I think!).

**Am I doing something wrong or effectively the function is bugged?**

NOTEs:

- I'm using Genesis Framework (just in case it may be useful to understand the context)
- Wordpress version is `4.9.4`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is caused probably by your theme or another plugin, filtering on `wp_nav_menu_args` and changing the `items_wrap` value.  I tested your provided code and the output was correct, using blank WordPress 4.9.4 installation.

You could try passing `items_wrap` with default value:

```
wp_nav_menu( [
    'menu' => 'Primary Navigation',
    'menu_class' => 'this-is-the-menu-class',
    'menu_id' => 'this-is-the-menu-id',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'this-is-the-container-class',
    'container_id' => 'this-is-the-container-ID',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>'
] );
```

But if something is filtering that out, it wouldn't make a difference.

I recommend adding this to your child theme's functions.php file, to remove all filters and see if that fixes it (to prove it is a filter causing your problem):

```
remove_all_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

You can also add this to your child theme's functions.php, to dump out on screen, the `$args` array, where you can check the value of `items_wrap`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_wp_nav_menu', 'smyles_dump_nav_menu_args', 9999, 2 );

function smyles_dump_nav_menu_args( $null, $args ){
    ob_start();

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($args);
    echo '</pre>';

    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
}
```

Returning a true value (in our case, it's HTML) to this filter will cause it to echo on page, when `echo` is passed true in the `wp_nav_menu`

Make sure to add `echo` and set `true` in `wp_nav_menu` call:

```
wp_nav_menu( [
    'menu' => 'Primary Navigation',
    'menu_class' => 'this-is-the-menu-class',
    'menu_id' => 'this-is-the-menu-id',
    'container' => 'div',
    'container_class' => 'this-is-the-container-class',
    'container_id' => 'this-is-the-container-ID',
    'echo' => true
] );
```

Comment: Ok, I've tried your suggestions. Removing all filters through `remove_all_filters( 'wp_nav_menu_args' );` doesn't solve the problem. Printing out the arguments, show them correctly (with and without the removal of all filters): so it seems that the problem exists, but isn't caused by any filter... On the installation I'm using there is only Genesis Framework installed and the child theme I'm working on. But it isn't the cause as I haven't added nothing related to menu. The problem is on Genesis side: I've to discover where it is... Suggestions?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this **exact** problem : the menu_class going on the container and the ul having no class at all.

Turns out this was due to me forgetting to check a menu location when creating the menu in my admin panel.

Instead of giving you an error, wordpress uses a default menu location and for some weird behind-the-scene reason it causes this.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/257671)

Comment: This actually helped me solving my problem (I checked the box but Wordpress didn't saved it somehow). And it does suggest a fix to the initial question in my opinion since it points out at one possible issue in the setup that would result in this behaviour. No reason for downvoting...

Comment: This solved my problem! And, it is actually written in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and came to the conclusion that this was happening because I had not created the menu in the wordpress admin panel.

What you have to do is **create a menu** in the admin panel and use that menu to locate the menu you created in the code.

Comment: That's correct, and it solves this problem!